# Connecting to MySQL over an SSH Tunnel with Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have a Linux instance with MySQL running. I got the MySQL connectors and I'm trying to setup a new connection to the database in Visual Studio. But it is on Amazon Web Services and the connection needs to be done over an SSH tunnel. I've got it running on MySQL Workbench but it doesn't seem like Visual Studio provides an option for that.

Is that possible ?

Here is the prompt I'm talking about : [image]

Comment: Is your mysql running on rds or the instance itself, if its on rds, have you authorized your ip in amazon?

Comment: You may be able to do this with the Devart MySQL connector.  Not sure, but it does seem more capable than Sun's connector.  http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/

Comment: It's on an EC2 instance. The ports are authorized through a profile. And okay I'll check out Deviart. Can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Or MySQL Workbench, it has SSH tunneling built in.
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/